# Where can I edit "X-UA-Compatible" to my Magento2 Store?

Tags: magento2

As I saw the source from the front end of the site. 
I would like to edit

> meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"

It seems to me that there should be something like web.config but I cannot find a file. 
Which file is suppose to be edited for X-UA-Compatible?

Comment: in which page did you see this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a theme and edit/create **default_head_blocks.xml** under:

`app/design/frontend/{{Vendor}}/{{Theme}}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="x_ua_compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    </head>
</page>
```